# Listview scrollbar ends-Windows store apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to fire an event when my listview scrollbar scrolled to the bottom.I googled and ended up in [Mikeal's Page](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-automatically-scrolling-listview-to-bottom-and-detecting-when-listview-is-scrolled/).But am not sure how to exactly proceed with the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ScrollBar.Scroll event and use the following event handler:

```
private void MyListView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) 
{

    ScrollBar scrollbar = e.OriginalSource as ScrollBar;

    if (scrollbar.Value == scrollbar.Maximum) 
    {
       // the scrollbar is at the bottom
    }

}
```

Comment: so when will your MyListView_Scroll gets fired?

Comment: @KhanXc It will be fired every time the ListView scrolls. That is why you need to check to see if has reached the bottom within the event handler. There is not a separate event for it reaching the bottom so this is necessary.